# Store a list of interface/type in typescript

Tags: typescript

I am trying to do something new but I have a small problem :

I have the following=>

```
export interface SynchGroupSubject {
  type: SynchGroupEvent;
  target: any;
}

export enum SynchGroupEvent {
  ADD_MAP,
  REMOVE_MAP
}
```

In a service I have the following

```
  public createNewSynchGroup(id?: string): Observable<SynchGroupSubject> {
    const subject = new Subject<SynchGroupSubject>();
    this.synchronizedGroupSubject.set(id, subject);
    return subject.asObservable();
  }
```

now, with this I am able to subscribe and follow update event =>

```
this.synchObs = this.mapSynchService.createNewSynchGroup(this.synchID);
this.synchObs.subscribe(event => this.synchEventHandler(event));
synchEventHandler(event: SynchGroupSubject) {
 switch (event.type) {
  case SynchGroupEvent.ADD_MAP:
       //event.target is type any
    break;
  default:
  break;

 }
}
```

the problem is, I want to type the target so that in the switch, I know what I deal with. right now, target is typed any, but I want to bind a type related to the type event.

The simple way would be to make a multitude of types, like this :

```
export interface ADD_MAP_TYPE {
  type: SynchGroupEvent;
  target: MyTypedTarger;
}
```

and do

```
synchEventHandler(event: SynchGroupSubject) {
 switch (event.type) {
  case SynchGroupEvent.ADD_MAP:
       event.target = event.target as ADD_MAP_TYPE;
    break;
  default:
  break;

 }
```

but I would like something SynchGroupEventType.ADD_MAP.

I thought about using namespace, but it is overkill.

also, if I want to dispatch and event

```
  public dispatchSynchedEvent(id: string, type: SynchGroupEvent, value: any) 
  {
     myElement.next({
       type: type,
       target: value,
     })
  }
```

Here to, my value is any, I would like that I could to the following

```
  public dispatchSynchedEvent(id: string, type: SynchGroupEvent, value: any) 
  {
     myElement.next({
       type: type,
       target: value as , // get the type of the value thx to the SynchGroupEvent type
     })
  }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It really looks like you should be using a [discriminated union](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#discriminated-unions) for `SynchGroupSubject`.  Right now you are using type assertions to tell the compiler which type of `target` you have when you check the `type` property, and you have to manually keep track of that mapping.  Discriminated unions pretty much give you that functionality for free.  Let's look at an example:

```
export enum SynchGroupEvent {
    ADD_MAP,
    REMOVE_MAP
}

// made-up example target interfaces    
interface MyAddTarget { a: string };
interface MyRemoveTarget { r: number };

// a discriminated union
type SynchGroupSubject = {
    type: SynchGroupEvent.ADD_MAP,
    target: MyAddTarget
} | {
    type: SynchGroupEvent.REMOVE_MAP,
    target: MyRemoveTarget
}

function synchEventHandler(event: SynchGroupSubject) {
    switch (event.type) {
        case SynchGroupEvent.ADD_MAP:
            event.target; // known by the compiler to be MyAddTarget
            event.target.a; // okay
            event.target.r; // error
            break;
        default:
            event.target; // known by the compiler to be MyRemoveTarget
            event.target.a; // error
            event.target.r; // okay
            break;
    }
}
```

[Link to code in Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#src=enum%20SynchGroupEvent%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20ADD_MAP%2C%0A%20%20%20%20REMOVE_MAP%0A%7D%0A%0A%2F%2F%20made-up%20example%20target%20interfaces%20%20%20%20%0Ainterface%20MyAddTarget%20%7B%20a%3A%20string%20%7D%0Ainterface%20MyRemoveTarget%20%7B%20r%3A%20number%20%7D%0A%0A%2F%2F%20a%20discriminated%20union%0Atype%20SynchGroupSubject%20%3D%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20type%3A%20SynchGroupEvent.ADD_MAP%2C%0A%20%20%20%20target%3A%20MyAddTarget%0A%7D%20%7C%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20type%3A%20SynchGroupEvent.REMOVE_MAP%2C%0A%20%20%20%20target%3A%20MyRemoveTarget%0A%7D%0A%0Afunction%20synchEventHandler%28event%3A%20SynchGroupSubject%29%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20switch%20%28event.type%29%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20case%20SynchGroupEvent.ADD_MAP%3A%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20event.target%3B%20%2F%2F%20known%20by%20the%20compiler%20to%20be%20MyAddTarget%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20event.target.a%3B%20%2F%2F%20okay%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20event.target.r%3B%20%2F%2F%20error%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20break%3B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20default%3A%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20event.target%3B%20%2F%2F%20known%20by%20the%20compiler%20to%20be%20MyRemoveTarget%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20event.target.a%3B%20%2F%2F%20error%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20event.target.r%3B%20%2F%2F%20okay%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20break%3B%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0A%7D%0A%0A)

This all works the way you want, right?  The individual cases in the `switch` statement are automatically inferred by the compiler to have the strongly-typed `event.target` corresponding to the `event.type` property.

Okay, hope that helps.  Good luck!

Answer (score 1):

> [@jcalz's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55760620) is the proper way to to it and should be the accepted answer. Please read his answer first to understand the idea of *discriminated union*.

I want to provide a complementary method to jcalz's answer, a "trick", which might be useful in some situation.

Now that you have declared the enum, if your `SynchGroupSubject` has a fixed shape like `{ type, target }`, then you might want to declare your target type this way. This syntax looks more readable to me.

```
enum SynchGroupEvent {
    ADD_MAP,
    REMOVE_MAP
}

type SynchGroupEventTarget = {
    [SynchGroupEvent.ADD_MAP]: { a: string };
    [SynchGroupEvent.REMOVE_MAP]: { r: number }
}
```

Here's the trick, instead of manually write a union type, we can use [mapped types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#mapped-types) to derive the discriminated union `SynchGroupSubject` from the two types above.

```
type SynchGroupSubject = {
    [K in SynchGroupEvent]: {
        type: K;
        target: SynchGroupEventTarget[K];
    }
}[SynchGroupEvent]
```

A bonus of this method is code reusability. If such pattern appears frequently, you can also generalize it to a utility type.

```
type BuildSubject<Enum extends keyof TargetMap, TargetMap> = {
    [K in Enum]: {
        type: K;
        target: TargetMap[K]
    }
}[Enum]

// usage
type SynchGroupSubject = BuildSubject<SynchGroupEvent, SynchGroupEventTarget>
type OtherSubject = BuildSubject<OtherEvent, OtherEventTarget>
```

Side note, the premise that these `Subject` types have fixed shape is important, otherwise my method wouldn't work.